# How to prevent massive fragmentation when copying large files to NTFS HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, file-transfer, defragment

I have some virtual machines, and for example the first one I'm looking at is 89gb.

Unfortunately when I try to copy it to a new drive it forms around 100,000 fragments (more than 1 per mb.)

---

I don't make a habit of running machines from the HDDs, but on rare occasion it's necessary and this makes it impossible - not to mention recovery times pulling it off the drive would be considerable to say the least.

---

- I already did a defrag and a free-space defrag prior to copying the files over (used Defraggler.)
- I've tried simply dealing with this after the fact, but it's not tenable. I have another 1.5TB of machines to back up and that will be millions upon millions of fragments.

It's a 12TB HDD on Windows 11.

Comment: I copy VHDDs much larger than what you describe to both network share drives and offline archive drives.  What problems specifically are you experiencing if you don't defrag the files?  I copy the VHDDs for my VMs on a routine basis and don't experience a problem with file fragmentation

Comment: Just slow access times. When an 80gb VHDD is split into 40,000 fragments it's slow to load, slow to use, slow to copy off the drive - slow in all regards that require disk access in any way.

Comment: Decades of using VMWare I have never seen that from a fraggmented VHDD.  What percentage of the system resources have you assigned to the VM?  I presume you came to the conclusion the fragmentation of the file is to blame, because if you degrag the file, the performance problem goes away?

Comment: The VMs are allowed to use basically any amount of system resources short of what VMWare suggests as an upper limit beyond which performance might suffer. -- All these days later I'm probably about a week out from finishing the defrags (which have been going since about January 3rd.) At least the end seems in sight.

Comment: It shouldn’t take a week to defrag a HDD. 12TB isn’t a very large disk.

Comment: I don't know what else to say except that it does. It's a 7200 RPM drive, nowhere near full, SMART all looks fine - but 40,000,000 fragments is no joke.